# Dois arrays em foreach js

Tags: javascript, html, array

Tenho uma função em JavaScript que manda requisições com o conteúdo das linhas de um `textarea`, é um looping que percorre um array e manda as requisições com os dados desses índices do array, o problema é que preciso criar mais 1 array com o conteúdo de outro `textarea` e mandar simultaneamente com o array do primeiro `textarea`, no caso:

```js
<script>
  function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var cor = coloracao.split("\n"); //esse e o textarea do qual quero criar o array
    var index = 0;
    linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){
      setTimeout(
        function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'bancodedados.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'nome=' + value + 'cor=' +arraycor,
            success: resultado
        })
      }, 10 * index);
    index = index + 0;
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: para oque estou fazendo esta e a melhor forma

Comment: estou enviando linha por linhas de um único textarea, porém preciso enviar linha por linha de dois textareas ao mesmo tempo em uma unica requisição

Comment: não, a quantidade vai variar conforme os dados recebidos

Comment: Então compensa fazer uma requisição só, e trabalhar com os dados no **back-end**.

Comment: isso vai abrir 1 processo só usando um looping no proprio php e deixar o retorno das respostas lento, preciso que o looping fique em js dessa forma se abriram multiplos processos no arquivo em php funcionando como threads e o retorno de cada requisição será mais rápido

Comment: Multiplicando o tempo em  `10 * index`  serve pra que?

Answer (score 2):

Creio que seja isto que você quer. Diante de 2 arrays, fazer um `forEach` na maior e puxar cada índice simultaneamente da menor até o limite:

```js
function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var coloracao = $("#coloracao").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var cor = coloracao.split("\n"); //esse e o textarea do qual quero criar o array
    var index = 0;
    
    var comp = linhaenviar.length >= cor.length;
    var maior = comp ? linhaenviar : cor;

    maior.forEach(function(value, i){

      var arraycor = comp ? (cor[i] != null ? cor[i] : ''): value;
      var linha = !comp ? (linhaenviar[i] != null ? linhaenviar[i] : ''): value;

      setTimeout(
         function(){
           console.log(linha+" / "+arraycor);
//            $.ajax({
//               url: 'bancodedados.php',
//               type: 'POST',
//               dataType: 'json',
//               data: 'nome=' + linha + 'cor=' +arraycor,
//               success: resultado
//        })
      }, 10 * index);
    index = index + 0;
    })
  }
```

```css
textarea{
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="bin_id">linha1
linha2
linha3
linha4
linha5
linha6</textarea>

<textarea id="coloracao">cor1
cor2
cor3
cor4
cor5</textarea>

<br />
<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
```